# React State Partly Lost

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I am trying to develop an editable table where the user can add rows of data and then send them to the back-end.

The app gets the current data in the componentDidMount() function.

The data is rendered on a react-table.

The user adds new rows with the Add button addrow() function.

The user save the data - sends updated data to back end. Here is when the error occurs:

**(ERROR)** In the saveDataMeasurements = (measurements) =>{} function the data received is printed on console.log has the desired state to be sent to the back end. However, the data sent is different to the one received. I couldn`t figure out why.

The code follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactTable from "react-table";
import 'react-table/react-table.css';
import update from 'react-addons-update';


class DataCollectionDetailB extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
       super(props)
       this.state = {
          data: []              
      };
    this.renderEditable = this.renderEditable.bind(this);
}

renderEditable(cellInfo) {
    return (
      <div
        style={{ backgroundColor: "#fafafa" }}
        contentEditable
        suppressContentEditableWarning
        onBlur={e => {
          const data = [...this.state.data];
          data[cellInfo.index][cellInfo.column.id] = e.target.innerHTML;
          this.setState({ data });
        }}
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html: this.state.data[cellInfo.index][cellInfo.column.id]
        }}
      />
    );
}

addrow = () =>{
    var objToday = new Date(),
    weekday = new Array('Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'),
    dayOfWeek = weekday[objToday.getDay()],
    domEnder = function() { var a = objToday; if (/1/.test(parseInt((a + "").charAt(0)))) return "th"; a = parseInt((a + "").charAt(1)); return 1 == a ? "st" : 2 == a ? "nd" : 3 == a ? "rd" : "th" }(),
    dayOfMonth = today + ( objToday.getDate() < 10) ? '0' + objToday.getDate() + domEnder : objToday.getDate() + domEnder,
    months = new Array('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'),
    curMonth = objToday.getMonth(),
    curYear = objToday.getFullYear(),
    curHour = objToday.getHours() > 12 ? objToday.getHours() - 12 : (objToday.getHours() < 10 ? "0" + objToday.getHours() : objToday.getHours()),
    curMinute = objToday.getMinutes() < 10 ? "0" + objToday.getMinutes() : objToday.getMinutes(),
    curSeconds = objToday.getSeconds() < 10 ? "0" + objToday.getSeconds() : objToday.getSeconds(),
    curMeridiem = objToday.getHours() > 12 ? "PM" : "AM";

    var today = curYear + "-" + (curMonth + 1) + "-" + dayOfMonth.slice(0,2)

    var newrow = new Array();
    newrow.id = 0;
    newrow.date = today;
    newrow.location_lat = 0;
    newrow.location_lon = 0;
    newrow.value = 0;       

    var updateData = update(this.state.data, {$push: [newrow]});

    this.setState({data:updateData});
}

saveDataMeasurements = (measurements) =>{
    //send measurements to back end
    console.log(measurements)   //the data here is ok   
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/measurementsinsert', {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    body: JSON.stringify({
        measurements: measurements   //this data is different and dont present the 2 rows added
        })
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data =>{ 
        console.log(data)           
    })
    .catch(error => { console.log('measurements insertions have failed', error); });
}

componentDidMount(){
    //get current measurements for field gs data collection task id on back end
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/measurementsfortaskgs', {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    body: JSON.stringify({              
        fieldgstask: this.props.field_gs_data_collection_task_id.fieldgsdc_id
        })
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        if (data.length > 0) {
            this.setState({data:data})
        }else {
            var newrow = new Array();
            newrow.id = 0;
            newrow.date = 0;
            newrow.location_lat = " ";
            newrow.location_lon = " ";
            newrow.value = " ";

            this.setState({data:newrow})
        }                       
    })
    .catch(error => { console.log('request failed', error); });
}

render() {
    console.log("PROPS", this.state)

    const { data } = this.state;
    const columns=[ 
                {
              Header: "Id Data Collection Task",
              accessor: "id"

            },
            {
              Header: "Date",
              accessor: "date",
              Cell: this.renderEditable
            },
            {
              Header: "Latitude",
              accessor: "location_lat",
              Cell: this.renderEditable
            },
            {
              Header: "Longitude",
              accessor: "location_lon",
              Cell: this.renderEditable
            },
            {
              Header: "Value",
              accessor: "value",
              Cell: this.renderEditable
            }
        ]

    return(
        <div>               
            <p>Input the measurements in the table bellow</p>
            <button type="button" id="add" onClick={this.addrow}> Add </button>
            <ReactTable
                data={data}
                columns={columns}
            />
            <button type="submit" onClick={() => { this.saveDataMeasurements(data) }}>Save</button>             
        </div>
    )}
}

export default DataCollectionDetailB;
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not fix the problem using react-table. I solve the problem by creating a simple html table getting onChange events and the same logic for everything else. It did work.

```
    import React from 'react'

    class Table extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          measurements: [],
        };
      }

      addrow = () =>{
        console.log("add row")

        var objToday = new Date(),
        weekday = new Array('Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'),
        dayOfWeek = weekday[objToday.getDay()],
        domEnder = function() { var a = objToday; if (/1/.test(parseInt((a + "").charAt(0)))) return "th"; a = parseInt((a + "").charAt(1)); return 1 == a ? "st" : 2 == a ? "nd" : 3 == a ? "rd" : "th" }(),
        dayOfMonth = today + ( objToday.getDate() < 10) ? '0' + objToday.getDate() + domEnder : objToday.getDate() + domEnder,
        months = new Array('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'),
        curMonth = objToday.getMonth(),
        curYear = objToday.getFullYear(),


        var today = curYear + "-" + (curMonth + 1) + "-" + dayOfMonth.slice(0,2)


        const newrow = {
          id: 0, 
          date: today, 
          location_lat: '',
          location_lon: '',
          value: '',
          sensor_id: 1,
          field_gs_data_collection_task_id: this.props.field_gs_data_collection_task_id.fieldgsdc_id 

        }

        this.setState({measurements:[...this.state.measurements, newrow]});

      }

      saveDataMeasurements = () =>{
          //send measurements to back end
          console.log("state of data", this.state.measurements)     
          fetch('http://localhost:3000/measurementsinsert', {
          method: 'post',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            body: JSON.stringify({
              measurements: this.state.measurements 
              })
         })
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(data =>{ 
            console.log(data)       
          })
          .catch(error => { console.log('measurements insertions have failed', error); });
      }

      componentDidMount(){
        //get current measurements for field gs data collection task id on back end
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/measurementsfortaskgs', {
          method: 'post',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            body: JSON.stringify({          
              fieldgstask: this.props.field_gs_data_collection_task_id.fieldgsdc_id
              })
          })
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(data => {
            if (data.length > 0) {
              this.setState({measurements:data})
            }else {
              var newrow = [];         
              this.setState({measurements:newrow})
            }               
          })
          .catch(error => { console.log('request failed', error); });
      }

      handleChange(index, dataType, value) {
        const newState = this.state.measurements.map((item, i) => {
          if (i === index) {
            return {...item, [dataType]: value};
          }
          return item;
        });

        this.setState({
           measurements: newState
        });
      }

      render() {
        //console.clear();
        console.log("props", this.props)
        console.log("measurements", this.state)
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.measurements));
        return (
            <div>
              <button type="button" id="add" onClick={this.addrow}> Add </button>
              <table className="table table-bordered">
                  <thead>
                      <tr>
                          <th>Id</th>
                          <th>Date</th>
                          <th>Latitude</th>
                          <th>Longitude</th>
                          <th>Value</th>
                      </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                      {this.state.measurements.map((row, index) => {
                          return (
                              <tr key={index}>
                                  <td>
                                    <input onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(index, 'id', e.target.value)} 
                                           type='number' 
                                           //className='form-control' 
                                           //step='1' min="1"
                                           value={this.state.measurements[index].id}/>
                                  </td>
                                  <td>
                                    <input onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(index, 'date', e.target.value)} 
                                           type='text' 
                                           className='date'
                                           value={this.state.measurements[index].date}/>
                                  </td>
                                  <td>
                                    <input onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(index, 'location_lat', e.target.value)} 
                                           type='text'
                                           className='form-control'  
                                           //placeholder='6.00'
                                           value={this.state.measurements[index].location_lat}/>
                                  </td>
                                   <td>
                                    <input onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(index, 'location_lon', e.target.value)} 
                                           type='text'
                                           className='form-control'  
                                   //placeholder='6.00'
                                           value={this.state.measurements[index].location_lon}/>
                                  </td>
                                  <td>
                                    <input onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(index, 'value', e.target.value)} 
                                           type='number'
                                           className='form-control'  
                                           //placeholder='6.00'
                                           value={this.state.measurements[index].value}/>
                                  </td>
                              </tr>
                          );
                      })}
                  </tbody>
              </table>
              <button type="submit" onClick={this.saveDataMeasurements}>Save</button>
            </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default Table;
```